# Sublime Text Plugin: Disable horizontal scrolling and also don't word wrap

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I like to have as many Sublime Text windows side by side as possible, so I disable the gutter and line numbers and all that so the windows are exactly 80 characters wide. But then Sublime Text insists on scrolling horizontally a bit, past column 80. That's especially annoying when using two-finger scroll with a trackpad as I'm constantly having to nudge the view back to the left.

I can enable `word_wrap` and that disables the horizontal scroll, which would be great except, even with `wrap_width`, I can't make wrapping happen only after column 80. If wrap_width is greater than or equal to the window width it insists on wrapping at slightly less than the window width, which is exactly 80 characters.

Assuming I'm correct that the standard settings don't let me simultaneously disable horizontal scrolling and word wrap, is this possible via the plugin API?

Comment: For testing, can you explain exactly how are you going about setting the window width to exactly 80 columns? Also, will multiple ST2 panes not work for you?

Comment: my sublime on lubuntu disables horizontal scrolling when word wrap is on. can you provide more details about your config?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and the only solution I could find is to manually focus each window then View > Word Wrap Column > Automatic. This will fix the issue but it must be done for each window you're using individually. Taking the extra 30 seconds to do this manually saves me much more time over the course of the day. I wish we could fix it through preferences/settings but it doesn't appear so in ST2.

Comment: Are you using full screen/distraction free mode? I dont use it, but coworkers complain about it having issues, some related to word wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

In this page http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/file-type-preferences

It seemed wordWrap and horizontal scrolling is binded(?).

> wordWrap: Set to false for horizontal scrolling. Defaults to true.

So

> wantVerticalScrollBar: Set to false to hide the vertical and horizontal scroll bars. Defaults to true. wantHorizontalScrollBar true

I'm not sure if it works modify on console (commands in page).

Hope helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

1. view > word-wrap-column > automatic
2. view > click on "word wrap"